# SetViewNames, spring 4 and thymeleaf and java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I try to develop an aplication that just has to send a email with an image. 
I saw some solutions that refer configuring the following property

```
<property name="viewNames" value="templates/*, pages/*" />
```

but I dont know how I have to configure in java way, thus this way doesnt works:
thymeleaf.setViewNames("templates/*"), 
However, it is appearing an error message:

```
2015-11-01 18:30:31.481 ERROR 1003 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "error": Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
2015-11-01 18:30:31.483 ERROR 1003 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-11-01 18:30:31.484 ERROR 1003 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
```

This is the code:

the configuration

```
@Bean 
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver=new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafView(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleaf = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

    thymeleaf.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    thymeleaf.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    thymeleaf.setOrder(1);
    return thymeleaf;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver SourceTemplateResolver(){
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver sourceTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

    sourceTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    sourceTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return sourceTemplateResolver;
}
```

The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:remove="all">Template for HTML email with inline image</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<p> Hello, everybody!</p>
<p> You have been successfully subscribed to the <b>Fake newsletter</b> on</p>
<p>Your hobbies are:</p>
<p> You can find <b>your inlined image</b> just below this text.</p>

<p><img src="LogoLehrer.jpg" th:src="'cid:' + ${imageResourceName}"/></p>

<p> Regards, <br/> <em>The Thymeleaf Team</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/sendmail")
public void sendMail(final Locale locale, HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     @RequestParam("imageResourceName") final MultipartFile image)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {

    mailSender.send("lehrerxx@gmail.com", "prueba spring final", 
    "I have luck", "Lehrer", locale,request,
    response, image, image.getBytes(), image.getName());
}
```

And the method which sends an email:

```
public void send(String to, String subject, String body,
     String recipientName, String recipientEmail,
     Locale locale,HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response, final MultipartFile image,
     final byte[] imageBytes, final String imageResourceName) throws MessagingException {

    // final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
    final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext, locale);
    ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
    ctx.setVariable("mail", recipientEmail);
    ctx.setVariable("imageResourceName", imageResourceName); 
    final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("email_Template", ctx);


    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;

    helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setText(htmlContent, true); 

    final InputStreamSource imageSource = new ByteArrayResource(imageBytes);
    helper.addInline(image.getName(), imageSource, image.getContentType());
    this.javaMailSender.send(message);

}
```